# Google page speed insight and lighthouse behavior on blocking css ressources

Tags: google-pagespeed, next.js, lighthouse, vercel

I have a NextJs application, hosted on Zeit Now, that I've optimized so it can run in Google Page Speed Insight with a score of 100/100.
In order to pass the 'Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content' test, I had to generate a critical CSS for the landing page, inline it in a `<style/>` tag in `<head/>`, and move all the `<link rel="stylesheet"/>` before the end of the body tag.
Now, when I run an audit using Google Lighthouse, I sometimes get the 'Reduce render-blocking stylesheets' warning, and sometimes not.
When the warning is there, I'll get a first meaningful paint at around 2s, when it's not there, I'll get it at around 400ms.
So my question is, which one should I trust?

Comment: Putting CSS in the body is not the greatest of ideas. Lighthouse, AFAIK, wants you to deduce the critical CSS and then *inline* it in the head. The remaining CSS can then be injected via JavaSript, which would (again, going of memory here) make it non-blocking.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that I did inline the critical css in the head, but I still kept the css in the body. You made my day! I've loaded the css files in js (using require() in React), and I don't get the warning anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the general solution to avoid blocking css ressources, while maintaining a good first paint, is to inline the critical css via a '' tag in the `<head>`, and load the css files using javascript.
Using NextJS, a good solution is to inline the critical css using `index.js` (and anything elese in `pages`), and then load all css dependencies for each component, using `require()` after verifying `process.browser` (since it won't load server side).
For some reasons, Google Page Speed Insight didn't consider a bunch of `<link rel="stylesheet"/>` at the end of a `<body>` tag as blocking, but Google Lighouse did, and it shows when you look at the first meaningful paint.